# Problems on Android devices

Tags: support, mobile-web

I have two problems on Android:

1. There is no search field in the mobile version of the site.
2. The Android browser doesn't recognize the tags when you ask a new question.

Comment: Android is operating system, not a browser. What browser you use on your Android driven device?

Comment: Tried both the that comes with android and also firefox.

Comment: The question was to the "mobile" version of the site. @Manishearth did answer at least the 1st one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer (a), there is a search field, click the down arrow up top.

[image]

[image]

What do you mean by "android browser doesn't recognize the Tags"? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, found the search field. Tags - I write them but the browser (firefox) doesn't make them grey and if I submit it fails as no tags are there....